# Generating hfc-key-store cryptomaterial without Fabric-CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

.hfc-key-store wallet used by HFC SDK uses user certificates generated by Fabric-CA to connect to Fabric platform.

Is there a way to generate these certificates without Fabric-CA?

I assume it would involve re-purposing of Org user certificates generated by cryptogen. However, I would appreciate if someone can point me to a documentation that tells how to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the fabric-ca?  Are you thinking of using your own CA or just trying to reduce the number of components required?  cryptogen does generate material which can be used and I'll post an answer below later, but wanted to make sure I understand your end goal.

Comment: The latter interpretation is valid - I try to keep the number of moveable parts at a reasonable level. I assume that each organization will be autonomous in generating its own crypto but it does not strictly mean that they will choose Fabric-CA. Having said that, I am looking forward towards your explanation :)

Comment: Still waiting for the implementation?